# Calling a method from another method in the same class in C++

Tags: c++, methods

I wrote a method (that works fine) for `a()` in a class.  I want to write another method in that class that calls the first method so:

```
void A::a() {
  do_stuff;
}

void A::b() {
  a();
  do_stuff;
}
```

I suppose I could just rewrite `b()` so `b(A obj)` but I don't want to.  In java can you do something like `this.a()`.

I want to do `obj.b()` where `obj.a()` would be called as a result of `obj.b()`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want?

Comment: oh whoops! I had a different error causing this -- which I just fixed.

Comment: make sure a is defined before b, if b is calling a

Comment: If there is a variable in A::a() then how to access that variable in A::b() ?

Comment: @Darshan, If you meant a local variable in `A:a()` then you can't access it in `A::b()`. If you meant a class member, then you access it in the same way in any class method, by using its identifier.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That's exactly what you are doing.

Comment: The answer ^^^ here is not useful; the one below with +44 points is a LOT more insightful. I recommend to change the order in the long run. I will explain why: I came to this here via Google, and the answer was not helping me - but the answer below WITH the syntax made me realize that I simply forgot a (). So the answer below with the +44 points was more helpful for my case, whereas the "what you are doing" comment adds really almost nothing at all to it.

Answer (score 72):

What you have should work fine.  You can use "this" if you want to:

```
void A::b() {
  this->a();
  do_stuff;
}
```

or

```
void A::b() {
  this->A::a();
  do_stuff;
}
```

or

```
void A::b() {
  A::a();
  do_stuff;
}
```

but what you have should also work:

```
void A::b() {
  a();
  do_stuff;
}
```

Comment: I get an error: `invalid use of 'this' in non-member function`

Comment: is it a better practice to use `this` when referencing methods/properties of the class?

Comment: If there is a variable in `A::a()` then how to access that variable in `A::b()` ?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the code you wrote in your block would work just fine.  Just make sure you have both the a() and b() methods defined inside your class properly.

Answer (score 5):

There's one case in which you might have slightly unexpected results. That is if `A::a()` is virtual, `obj` actually has type `DerivedFromA`, and DerivedFromA::a overrides `A::a`. In that case, the simple call `a();` or the more verbose `this->a();` will not call A::a but DerivedFromA::a().

Now, this is probably intended, since class A declared a() to be virtual. But if you really don't mean it, you can ignore the virtual by writing the call either as

```
void A::b()
{
    A::a(); // or
    this->A::a(); //Both ignore the virtual-ness of a()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you have written there should work fine.  In C++ if you call `a` within `b` and both are instance methods of some class `A`, then you don't need to qualify it.  Both `a` and `b` are in each others' scope.